# Prolog - height (depth) of subtree

Tags: recursion, tree, prolog

I have the relation `child(X,Y)`, where `X` is the root/parent node and `Y` is the child node, hence a directed edge. I want to calculate the height `H` of each subtree from a specific root node `R` in dynamic relation `height(R, H)`.

My previous code:

```
child(a,b).
child(a,f).
child(f,g).
child(f,h).
child(b,c).
child(c,d).
child(b,e).
child(c,l).
child(l,j).

height(R, H) :-
    path(R,_,B,H),
    write(B).

path(X,Y,[X,Y],1) :-
    child(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|P],C) :-
    child(X,Z),
    path(Z,Y,P,Cn),
    C is Cn+1.
```

It finds all paths (and lengths) starting from a node `R`. Is there a way to find only the longest path in a n-nary tree recursively? Or should I save the tree structure in a list before?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to provide the path as an argument rather than `write` it:

```
height(Node, Height, Path) :- path(Node, _, Path, Height).
```

Which gives your results:

```
| ?- height(a, H, P).

H = 1
P = [a,b] ? ;

H = 1
P = [a,f] ? ;

...
```

When you use `write`, the results go to the display but they aren't captured for use in your program. You can use `setof/3` to collect a pairing of paths and their heights. Since `setof/3` orders the results in ascending order, it becomes straightforward to obtain the shortest (or longest) path starting at a given node:

```
max_height_path_for_node(Node, MaxHeight, MaxPath) :-
    setof(Height-Path, height(Node, Height, Path), Paths),
    reverse(Paths, [MaxHeight-MaxPath | _]).
```

`reverse/2` is used to get the maximum height to the front of the list, and you "pick off" the results from there.

To find the maximum path over all nodes:

```
max_height_path(MaxHeight, MaxPath) :-
    setof(Height-Path, Node^height(Node, Height, Path), Paths),
    reverse(Paths, [MaxHeight-MaxPath | _]).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`aggregate`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-aggregate) library, you can solve this with a one-liner:

```
height(R,H) :-
    aggregate(max(Hi),A^B^path(R,A,B,Hi),H).
```

Example queries:

```
?- height(A,H).
A = a,
H = 4 ;
A = b,
H = 3 ;
A = c,
H = 2 ;
A = f,
H = 1 ;
A = l,
H = 1.

?- height(a,H).
H = 4.

?- height(f,H).
H = 1.

?- height(f,3).
false.

?- height(A,3).
A = b ;
false.
```

You thus run the `max` aggregate over the height of each path that starts with the given root element `R` (and set `A` and `B` as discriminator arguments) and return the result as `H`.